# Print screen passthrough in windows remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I press the print screen button while using remote desktop, I want the print screen to go to the actual main computer (as opposed to the remote host). I dont want to change any other behavior.

Is this possible. If not what is the closest I can get?

Comment: If not what is the closest I can get?   Save the print to a file and then transfer the file to the main machine.

Answer (score 1):

The function of the PrtSc key on Windows is to capture the screen as an
image on the clipboard.

So what you need is :

1. Transmit the PrtSc key via RDP
2. Share the clipboard via RDP so only the client you can paste the image
   into any image editor and save it.

If RDP does not transmit the PrtSc key, but rather executes it locally,
use instead the key combination
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>.

To share the clipboard, in RDP use the "Show Options" drop-down,
Local Resources tab and tick the box next to the Clipboard option.
Now when connecting the clipboard will be the same on both sides
of the connection.

[image]